# Need to pass an id of current row to the query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that need outout ActiveAgents for each row base on branchId. now sure how make it work with branchId. when I have it like that inside my query it return 1 amouth for all the rows, but when I try it separate and pass branchId like this it works.

```
    …….
 ,(select Count(*)  from [TblAgencyContact] agent 
   left join [TblBranchMember] branchMember on agent.AgencyContactId = branchMember.AgencyContactId
                                                left join [TblBranch]branch  on branch.BranchId = branchMember.BranchId
                                               where agent.StatusId = 1 and branchMember.BranchId = branch.BranchId and 
                                               branchMember.BranchId = branch.BranchId) as ActiveAgents
,……

 from [TblBranch]branch
```

I don't know how to pass a `BranchId` for current row to it inside the query.

```
select 
    Count(*)  
from 
    [TblAgencyContact] agent 
left join 
    [TblBranchMember] branchMember on agent.AgencyContactId = branchMember.AgencyContactId
left join 
    [TblBranch] branch on branch.BranchId = branchMember.BranchId
where 
    agent.StatusId = 1 
    and branchMember.BranchId = branch.BranchId 
    and branchMember.BranchId = branch.BranchId 
    and branch.BranchId = 81
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top query is close, but you need to remember that you do not need to JOIN on the TblBranch table, because you are passing the appropriate value into the subquery.  Also, shouldn't the links be INNER JOINs? If there isn't a person in the TblBranchMember table, you wouldn't want to count the TblAgencyContact row, right?

```
(
    select Count(*)
    from [TblAgencyContact] agent 
    INNER join [TblBranchMember] branchMember 
        on agent.AgencyContactId = branchMember.AgencyContactId
    where agent.StatusId = 1 
        and branchMember.BranchId = branch.BranchId -- where branch is accessed in the outer query
) as ActiveAgents
```